# Set the maven local repository location in a pom.xml file?

Tags: java, maven

It's possible to set the maven local repository in settings.xml:

```
<localRepository>${user.home}/.m2/repository</localRepository>
```

And it's possible to set the maven local repository on the command line:

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.repo.local=repository
```

Is it possible to specify within the pom.xml itself?

Note: I'd like a way to specify, in the pom.xml, where maven initially searches for artifacts (by default, `~/.m2/repository`) and where maven installs artifacts via `mvn install` (by default, `~/.m2/repository`).

Comment: The first example is exactly what is used as default. If you like you can also use the second one give the parameter for the location... and to answer your question: No it is not possible to define the location of the local cache in the pom file..The question is why would you like to change it?

Comment: No, the question is how to change it - why isn't relevant :)

Comment: It is relevant to understand your motivation and of course get an idea of what you are trying to do or what kind of problem you are trying to solve. This helps and maybe I can suggest a better solution for your problem If I know the why. But If you don't like to be helped Ok..It is up to you....

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to the [Maven POM Reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories) and the [Guide to using multiple repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html), you can specify repositories in `pom.xml` too.

> There are two different ways that you can specify the use of multiple repositories. The first way is to specify in a POM which repositories you want to use

And according to [Introduction to repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html), you can use the `file://` protocol in `<url>`.

> Remote repositories refer to any other type of repository, accessed by a variety of protocols such as file:// and http://.

So the following works:

```
<project>
  ...
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>example-repo</id>
      <name>Example Repository</name>
      <url>file://path/to/your/local/repository</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
</project>
```

---

**Edit:**

Based on your comment and edit, you need to override the default repository and Maven home directory in `pom.xml`.

I've found a [topic about disabling central repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997219/disable-maven-central-repository), and tried out the answers, but Maven still uses the values from `settings.xml`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42455438/2418224) in another thread explains why:

> `settings.xml` allows you to override definitions in `pom.xml`, not the other way round.

So it's seems it is not possible to override the default mechanism from `pom.xml`, Maven will search for dependencies in repositories configured in `settings.xml` and will install to Maven home specified in that file.

Comment: Even with a repository set as above, maven will still, by default, download artifacts from and install artifacts to `~/.m2/repository` - IIRC, the above simply specifies a backup to download from and a target to deploy to. I'm looking to change - in the pom.xml - where the system initially searches for artifacts and uses as the destination fro the `mvn install` command.

Comment: @juzraai The definition of a repository has nothing to do with the definition of a local cache apart from that it does not make sense to define a repository on file base....

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is having to write the options every time when running maven, you can use a feature available since version 3.3.1 that allows you to set command line options in your project (or parent project of your module). Read @Brice's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48583079

So with this feature in mind, you can achieve a similar result by setting up a new `settings.xml` with the `<localRepository>` pointing to the location you desire and use `maven.config` in your project to make maven use the new `settings.xml`, which by the way can be anywhere you want.