# How to include libraried that are included on the server to pom?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, server

I have a Libery server local instalation, that have some .jar files included. I would like to include this files as dependacies or in some other way to my pom.xml.

server.xml :

```
...
<library id="DB2Type4"> 
   <fileset dir="path" includes="db22first.jar db2second.jar"/>
</library>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use local repository [ulr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51686612/set-the-maven-local-repository-location-in-a-pom-xml-file), or private maven repository server like Artifactory.