# How do i use IntelliJ with offline repository?

Tags: intellij-idea, maven-2

I already downloaded and installed the community version of Intellij. I made this switch after several encountered issues from A.S.

I have the offline_gmaven_stable.zip repository unpacked, but I don't know how to make IntelliJ check my local repository for missing dependencies.

Comment: Please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51686775/2960034

Comment: the answer wasnt really explanatory. I would appreciate a step-by-step Tutorial, Thanks..

Comment: You need to add your local repository in pom.xml:  <project>
  ...
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>example-repo</id>
      <name>Example Repository</name>
      <url>file://path/to/your/local/repository</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
</project>

Comment: Okay, I will try it and get back to you.

Comment: @y.bedrov, I couldnt find the pom fiile, I only located the settings.xml file.

Comment: Don't you create Maven based project?

Comment: no, i created an andriod project, i am learning to develop andriod programs using IntelliJ

Comment: Thanks, I have finally been able to fixed it. I just extracted my files into the ".m2/repository" folder, and that worked flawlessly...