# Maven ignore custom local repository

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to start my tests in an environment without an internet connection.
To do this, I need to save my dependencies in the project directory and specify Maven for this repository.

I copy repository folder from .m2 to project, write:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>project-repository</id>
        <url>file:${project.basedir}/repository</url>
        <releases>
            <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

and hoped that the maven would ignore the local m2 repository. But when I remove all the dependencies from m2, the maven still downloads them from the Internet. If i disconnected - the maven ignores the local repository and does not start.

```
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

How can I tell the maven to work only from the internal repository? Without custom setting.xml, only on *.pom .

Comment: you can once run a "mvn dependency:go-offline" wich will download all dependencies and plugins required. You can copy this one. Then run maven with -o in offline mode so it will not attempt to download anything. But it will need a local repository to work with.

Comment: Network/Firewall/Proxy issue `nodename nor servname provided, or `... or using an internal repository manager...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven is using the values from the `settings.xml` in `{M2_HOME}\conf\settings.xml`.

The issues here is that `settings.xml` allows you to override definitions in `pom.xml`, not the other way round. So you can override the tag `<localRepository>` in `settings.xml`, more on this [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/maven/change-local-repository-location/). Also [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42455351/override-mvn-settings-xml-in-your-pom-xml-define-only-project-specific-repos/42455438#42455438) in another thread explains why.

The other option is to set the maven local repository on the command line:

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.repo.local=repository
```

Comment: Thx! I dont know about overriding.